# pack build ：[analyzer] ERROR: failed to parse arguments: received 9 arguments, but expected 1

Tags: operating-system, pack, buildpack

After upgrading my macOS to Sonoma, running the **`pack build`** command with Cloud Native Buildpacks started resulting in an error. The command I used is:

```
pack build test --path . --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

The output ends with:

```
===> ANALYZING [analyzer] ERROR: failed to parse arguments: received 9 arguments, but expected 1 ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 3
```

I'm unsure which arguments the analyzer is referring to, as I only provided the name, path, and builder in my command. How can I determine which arguments are being passed incorrectly to the **`pack build`** command?

I tested the same file and same version of pack on other PC (windows and linux)
they all work well
I guess there maybe some problem of new MacOS.
but I cannot fix it.

Comment: Can you try with `--trust-builder` flag?

Comment: when I add this flag, still error:
ERROR: failed to parse arguments: received 11 arguments, but expected 1
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 3

Comment: sounds like an issue with your shell? have you tried with bash / another shell?

Comment: Not sure if it'll fix things, but `paketobuildpacks/builder:base` is the old builder. It's not being maintained and has an older set of buildpacks. You want to use `paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest` to get all of the latest buildpacks and updates. Also, helpful if you could post the output of `docker version`, `pack --version` and the full output of `pack build -v ...`.

Comment: Thanks frs, I updated the MacOS to 14.1.1 (23B81), and this bug disappeared, So I think it is the system bug, and thanks for your kind advices.